# Increment size with keeping square sizes

Tags: javascript, math

I need to increment a box size with fixed increments in Javascript, but also keeping the square sizes. I think there should be an 'easy' math function for this, but I can't figure it out. I tried something with `pow()` and `sqrt()` and long if-statements, but nothing seems to do the trick.

**Example:**
Let say I have a box of (WxH) 54 x 45 and my increments are 10, and I want to increase the height (with a button). With a normal increment of 10 the height will become 55, but I want it to first return the value of 54, so the box becomes square. Once it's 54 and I'm increasing the height again, it should continue at 55 again.

1. So my box is (WxH) 54 x 45
2. User clicks button "+" to increase the height
3. Box should become (WxH) 54 x 54
4. User clicks button "+" again to increase the height
5. Box should become (WxH) 54 x 55
6. User clicks button "+" again to increase the height
7. Box should become (WxH) 54 x 65
8. And so on...

The aspect ratio is not important.

I hope somebody can help me out, or at least point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. A picture would help. Do you want to keep a *consistent* aspect ratio? Or do you want things to become square when they're enlarged?

Comment: For example, if you increase the height by 10 and you want the box to have the same shape, the width should be increased by `10 * (54/45)` which is 12, meaning you'd have a 66 x 55 box. That's not square, however.

Comment: @Pointy I updated my question with some additional information, I hope it's clear now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pow`, `sqrt` and the likes won't help you, you simply have to do one special case. Something like this:

```
var step = 10, squareCase = null;

function increaseWidth() {
  if (squareCase !== null) {   // we are currently at the square case
    width = squareCase + step; // resume from remembered
    squareCase = null;         // and leave the special case
  }
  else if (width < height && width + step > height) {
    squareCase = width;       // remember value so we can resume sequence
    width = height;           // do the square now
  }
  else {
    width = width + step;     // default case
  }
}
```

When writing the corresponding decrementation, keep in mind that the `squareCase` variable contains the value *prior* to incrementation, so it should contain the already decremented value in the decrement case.

Comment: Thanks MvG, your code pointed me in the right direction. I've got it implemented now with your method. Thanks everyone for thinking with me!

Answer (score 0):

It's not quare what your asking but it should look something like this:

```
var boxGetter = function(w, h){
    // anonymouse function setting the original width and height
    return {
        // get the new height 
        // pass in the new width
        height: function(nw){
            return (w / h) * nw;
        },
        width: function(nh){
            return (h / w) * nh;
        }
    }
}

var getter = boxGetter(54, 45);

console.log(getter.height(54+10)); // 66
console.log(getter.width(45+10)); // 45.83
```